# How can I use of norm(a,b) in matlab if a, b are double type?

Tags: matlab, norm

I must to use `angle = atan2(norm(cross(a,b)),dot(a,b))`, for calculating the angle between two vectors `a,b` and these are double type and `norm` is undefined for this type.  How do I resolve this problem?  I need to calculate the angle between two vectors this way.

Comment: i appreciate all your help, I do these works but not change.

Comment: it's my code:I=imread('thesis.jpg');
I = double(I);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
          angle = atan2(norm(cross(I(i,j,:),I_avg)),dot(I(i,j,:),I_avg));         
     end
 end

Comment: i want to calculate angel or cos() or tan() between I(i,j,:) and I_avg for thresholding but by cos() it is not good and i have to try tan()

Comment: now when i run this code it has an error:Undefined function 'norm' for input arguments of type 'double' and
attributes 'full 3d real'.

Comment: Now I know why.  Your vector is actually a `1x1x3` vector.  `norm` interprets this as 3D data when `norm` doesn't support this.  You should have put this code in your post in the beginning.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: excuse me i'm new in this site and dont khow how to work.

Comment: That's fine.  Next time just edit your post with this new information.  It prevents us from going back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments, you have shown us how you are actually writing out the angle calculation and it is not the same as how you have put it in your post.

```
atan2(norm(cross(I(i,j,:),I_avg)),dot(I(i,j,:),I_avg));
```

`I` is an image you are loading in.  I'm assuming it's colour because of the way you are subsetting `I`. Because `I` is a 3D matrix, doing `I(i,j,:)` will give you a `1 x 1 x 3` vector when in fact this has to be a 1D vector.  `norm` does not recognize this structure which is why you're getting this error.  Therefore, you need to use [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) to remove the singleton dimensions so that this will become a `3 x 1` vector, rather than a `1 x 1 x 3` vector.  As such, you need to rewrite your code so that you're doing this instead.  Bear in mind that in your comments, `angle` is always overwritten inside the `for` loop, so you probably want to save the results of each pixel.  With this, you probably want to create a 2D array of angles that will store these results.  In other words:

```
I=imread('thesis.jpg'); 
I = double(I);
angles = zeros(m,n);
I_avg = squeeze(I_avg); %// Just in case 
for i=1:m 
    for j=1:n 
        pixels = squeeze(I(i,j,:)); %// Add this statement and squeeze
        angles(i,j) = atan2(norm(pixels,I_avg)),dot(pixels,I_avg)); %// Change
    end 
end
```

---

## Minor note

MATLAB has a built-in function called [`angle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html) that determines the angle from the origin to a complex number in the complex plane.  It is not recommended you call your variable `angle` as this will unintentionally shadow over the `angle` function, and any other code that you create from this point onwards may rely on that actual `angle` function, and you will get unintended results.

## Another minor note

Using `i` and `j` as loop variables is not recommended.  These letters are reserved for the complex number, and this can produce unintentional results.  Take a look at this question and post by [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai) here - [Using i and j as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).  As such, it is suggested you use other variable names instead.

Comment: +1 `norm`, `a`, `b`, something must be wrong (different than expected) between them.

Comment: does here allow betting? I'll give you 15 rep if you don't have a green tick in 2 days

Comment: @Yvon - Ahahaha you have a lovely sense of humour.  My bet is that I won't hear from the OP again.  I solved his/her problem, and off they go about with their business.  The only thing I really got from all of this is to make sure the OP posts everything about the question that doesn't distract from the overall goal.  The more information like this, the better.

Comment: thank you so much for your help and this site.it is very good and useful.thank you again.

Comment: i'm work on face retrieval and have a lot of question about it and its simulation!

Comment: @SiminSoleymanpour - You're welcome.  I've also slightly edited my question so you can store the angles for each pixel in the image.  Please consider accepting my answer too by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left underneath the up and down voting buttons.  Thanks!

Comment: if i have other questions about another part of my code,i ask here in comments or other post?

Comment: both answer of you is good and i want to give green tick to both answer .but i dont know how do this work/

Comment: @SiminSoleymanpour - Unfortunately you can't accept both answers :( You can only accept one.  As such, choose either my answer or Yvon's.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As @rayryeng has successfully answered this question, I would like to turn my post into a more general one by sharing my experience in debugging in Matlab. I hope anyone who somehow managed to find this post get more or less thinking about the habits a good programmer should have.

The question goes like: *"How would I do if I get errors?"*

1. Here's [an excellent article by Eric](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) in which he lists the rule-of-thumbs when you encounter a bug and wish to get rid of it. It's originally been cited by Stackoverflow, and that's the reason I read it.
2. If you still get no clue / idea how you can play with your code, see how this person does:

### Pin-point the buggy line

0. (The number should start with 0) Make sure before running a script, you [`clear`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html) out any previously stored variables, including [the notorious `i` and `j`'s (you should never see them in any workspace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab). If any one is needed for the buggy code to run, [`save('buggy.mat','importantvar')`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) before `clear` and [`load('buggy.mat')`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) after clear.

   By doing so, you can isolate your buggy code from anything else, which could have bad influences. For example, in a previously called script, there is a line

   ```
   double = [2,4,6]; % you should never name a variable `double`
   ```

   and in the next script, you have

   ```
   >> e = str2num('uint8(200)')
   e =
     200
   >> double(e)
   Index exceeds matrix dimensions. 
   >> 
   >> f = single(2.36)
   f =
       2.3600
   >> double(f)
   Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
   logicals. 
   >>
   ```

   The reason is `double` is no longer [an inbuild function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), but a user-defined variable. Too bad to pick up a name carelessly!

   ....anyway, let's `clear` the workspace and get rid of `double`.

   ```
   >> clear
   ```
1. Read the error message, **thoroughly**.

   Now let's begin with OP's problem. The original code (trimmed) goes like this -

   ```
   img = imread('peppers.png');
   a = img(300,200,:);
   b = img(200,300,:);
   d = norm(cross(a,b));
   ```

   .... hence the error

   ```
   Undefined function 'norm' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
   Error in untitled (line 6)
   d = norm(cross(a,b));
   ```

   Most beginners are only interested in the first line of the error message, which by it alone usually doesn't provide any useful help, or only in the red color, which leads to the famous question "my code does not work!"

   But *think twice*. You still have another 2 lines unread! `Error in untitled (line 6)` says I'm running a script named `untitled` and the (first) error lies in **line 6**, and the code in that line is `d = norm(cross(a,b));`.

   Now, at least you know a little more about your code - "My code `d = norm(cross(a,b));` doesn't work!"

   Although most likely we may also vote this kind of question to get closed, it's still much much better than a simply "It does not work!".
2. Now we can pin-point the buggy line

   ```
   try
   %     this line will raise an error
       d = norm(cross(a,b));
   catch err
       disp(err.message)
   end
   ```

### Look into the functions

First, make sure the inner function [`cross`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cross.html) works as expected -

```
    >> cross(a,b)
    ans(:,:,1) =
        0
    ans(:,:,2) =
      255
    ans(:,:,3) =
        0
    >>
```

Good. So now we can even narrow down the error to the outer [`norm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html).

One more thing to mention. You can always find Mathworks' documentation for *any* in-build function, by typing "matlab *function*", such as "matlab norm" in Google (or any other search engine) and clicking on the first result. If you prefer, you can also type in Matlab command window `doc _function_` such as `doc norm` and read the doc in Matlab. It's of course a pleasure of us on Stackoverflow to give you the reference by doing the same thing, but it takes a longer time because a human is, in this aspect, always slower than a search engine.

The error reads `Undefined function 'norm' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.`. So the input for `norm` should not be `uint8`, unsigned 8-bit integer. But what should it be?

```
% why `norm` "does not work"? 
% this line runs perfectly well
norm(cross([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))
% so what is working? 
class([1,2,3]) % so `norm` works for `double`
```

One thing we can do now is convert `a` and `b` to double precision. Let's try it now.

```
% try fixing 'uint8' error
a2 = double(a);
b2 = double(b);
whos a b % now they are double, which `norm` should work for
try
%     this line will raise an error
    d = norm(cross(a2,b2));
catch err
    disp(err.message)
end
```

Now the error becomes `Input must be 2-D.`. What's wrong with the input?

```
% what is "must be 2-D" error? 
size(a2) % a2 is 3-D
disp(b2) % b2 is also 3-D
```

This gives output in command window

```
ans =
     1     1     3
(:,:,1) =
   255
(:,:,2) =
   150
(:,:,3) =
     0
```

In OP's problem, he/she is trying to calculate something about color difference (to the best of my knowledge) which involves [the angle between two color vectors](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/808005) in RGB space. So the vectors are needed. With [`imread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html), each pixel of the image is stored as 3 elements in the matrix, first 2 dimension being its physical position, the 3 dimension being RGB channel components. Hence pixel(200,300) with color rgb[255,150,0] is stored by us in variable `b` wihch is a 3-D vector.

By understanding *what we need* and *what Matlab can do*, we can combine these two points into one. We need the norm of the cross product of `a` and `b`, while the useful information (the 3 component values) is stored in the 3rd dimension. Matlab can calculate the norm of the cross product of a vector with all its information in the 1st dimension. (Here, "dimension" refers to that of the Matlab variable; a vector with 3 elements in its 1st dimension is physically a 3-D vector).

After thinking twice, we are now able to debug our code - just put all 3 elements into the 1st dimension.

```
% so we want the 3 elements in the 3rd dimension become in the 1st dim
a3 = squeeze(a2);
b3 = reshape(b2,numel(b2),[]);
try
    d = norm(cross(a3,b3));
catch err
    disp(err.message)
end
d
```

Bonus: If by default Matlab treats a 3-D vector as a "1-D array", then most probably the `cross` function has not been working correctly. Let's make a check -

```
>> clear
>> a = [1,2,3]
a =
     1     2     3
>> b=[4,5,6]
b =
     4     5     6
>> cross(a,b)
ans =
    -3     6    -3
>>
```

The result should be the same as the one we can get by calculating by hand.

Now if we put the components into the 3rd dimension of the variable -

```
>> clear
>> a(1,1,:)=[1,2,3]
a(:,:,1) =
     1
a(:,:,2) =
     2
a(:,:,3) =
     3
>> b(1,1,:)=[4,5,6]
b(:,:,1) =
     4
b(:,:,2) =
     5
b(:,:,3) =
     6
>> cross(a,b)
ans(:,:,1) =
    -3
ans(:,:,2) =
     6
ans(:,:,3) =
    -3
>>
```

.... seems OK. `cross` also puts the result in the 3rd dimension. In fact, Mathworks' documentation says

> If A and B are vectors, then they must have a length of 3.
>
> If A and B are matrices or multidimensional arrays, then they must
> have the same size. In this case, the cross function treats A and B as
> collections of three-element vectors. The function calculates the
> cross product of corresponding vectors along the first array dimension
> whose size equals 3.

At last, one thing is always correct to anyone who wants to do something with programming - be cautious and prudent when writing your code.

Comment: +1 - Very nice.  I didn't consider the fact that a script called `norm` could be existing too.

Comment: I figured out why the OP is experiencing the problem.  `norm` was interpreting the vector as a three dimensional array.  He/she was extracting a 3D vector from an image by doing `I(i,j,:)` which produces a `1 x 1 x 3` array.  `norm` does not support 3D matrices, which is why they were getting the error.  I found out just now because the OP posted the actual code that they were doing in the comments.  Why can't they just give us all the info in the beginning?

Comment: @rayryeng Since your answer is good and complete, there is no use I post another duplicate; but after thinking for a while I decided to put something more in this post. Hoping this can bring help to more people.

Comment: Very nice answer Yvon.  I'd give you more votes, but I've already voted.  I'm almost tempted to give you a bounty for such a quality answer!